# Почему не обрабатывает исключение ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException? Java

Tags: java

Создан метод, с помощью которого устанавливаются часы. Имеется обрабатываемое исключение `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Но почему, при вводе значения `set_value = 33`, исключение не обрабатывается (часов ведь максимум 24)?

Ссылка на описание: `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set-int-int-`

```
public void setHours(int set_value) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    try {
        objCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, set_value);
        getMessageTime();
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a) {
        getMessageErrorRangeOfValues();
        objCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    }
}
```

**UPD:**

Оказывается, исключение бросается, если объект класса `Calendar` установлен в режим `non-lenient'.

**Оригинальная цитата:**

Leniency

Calendar has two modes for interpreting the calendar fields, lenient and non-lenient. When a Calendar is in lenient mode, it accepts a wider range of calendar field values than it produces. When a Calendar recomputes calendar field values for return by get(), all of the calendar fields are normalized. For example, a lenient GregorianCalendar interprets MONTH == JANUARY, DAY_OF_MONTH == 32 as February 1.

When a Calendar is in non-lenient mode, it throws an exception if there is any inconsistency in its calendar fields. For example, a GregorianCalendar always produces DAY_OF_MONTH values between 1 and the length of the month. A non-lenient GregorianCalendar throws an exception upon calculating its time or calendar field values if any out-of-range field value has been set. `

**Решение:**

Установить режим `non-lenient' с помощью метода`setLenient()`вот так`obj.setLenient(false);`. По умолчанию режим ставится как`true`.

Тогда код выглядит так:

```
public void setHours(int set_value) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    try {
        objCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, set_value);
        getMessageTime();
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a) {
        getMessageErrorRangeOfValues();
        objCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    }
}
```

Но после установки режима в `false` начинает выбрасывать другое исключение - `IllegalArgumentException`. Хорошо, попытаемся обработать и это исключение. Тогда код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
public void setHours(int set_value) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, IllegalArgumentException {
    try {
        objCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, set_value);
        getMessageTime();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException i) {
        getMessageErrorRangeOfValues();
        objCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    }
}
```

Но вот незадача. Опять выбрасывает исключение `Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:`.

**Ответ: разбираюсь на данный момент**

Comment: вопрос только для проблемы, с которой вы столкнулись. Если вы самостоятельно нашли решение, то не надо писать его в вопрос. Оформите свое решение ответом в поле "ответить на собственный вопрос"

Answer (score 1):

Дочитывайте документацию:

```
objCalendar.setLenient(false);
```

Comment: Сделал так:  `Calendar objCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();`, потом `objCalendar.setLenient(false);` , и при передаче методу значения больше 24 получил другое исключение: `Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HOUR_OF_DAY`

Comment: @n199a Значит его и надо обрабатывать.

Comment: опять бросает исключение `IllegalArgumentException` (см. в моем топике, я описал шаги последовательно)

Comment: @n199a Возможно, ноль - недействительное значение, и исключение возникает в блоке `catch`.

Comment: до конца не понял, что означает ваше выражение `Возможно, ноль - недействительное значение`. Возможно ли обработать исключение `IllegalArgumentException`, поместив его в блок `catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a)` ?

Comment: @n199a Я предполагаю, что одно исключение обрабатывается, а другое возникает в `objCalendar.set`, которое вызываеатся в блоке `catch`.

Comment: дело в том, что в блок `catch` даже не попадаем, потому что часы устанавливаются, то есть выполняется то, что в блоке `try`. P.S. Пробовал ещё поменять значение с `0` на любое в диапазоне `от 1 до 23`, всё равно исключение.

Comment: @n199a Значит исключение возникает где-то в другом месте.